# PHPUnit won't run over Generator function

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm replacing a method that returns an array of objects:

```
private function getValues(array $rows)
{
    $values = [];

    foreach ($rows as $data) {
        $values[] = $this->mapToModel($data);
    }

    return $values;
}
```

With a generator instead:

```
private function getValues(array $rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $data) {
        yield $this->mapToModel($data);
    }
}
```

But my tests don't seem to enter/cover this `getValues()` function (called from within a public method) at all. Is this normal behaviour?

**UPDATE**

I'm runnning: **PHP 7.2.21 with Xdebug 2.7.2**

Here is the relevant parts of the test and code:

```
class SettlementDB
{
    /**
     * @var \PDO
     */
    private $db;

    /**
     * @param \PDO $db
     */
    public function __construct(\PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        $q = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table');
        $q->execute();
        return $this->getValues($q->fetchAll());
    }

    /**
     * @param array $rows
     * @return Generator
     */
    private function getValues($rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $data) {
            yield $this->mapToModel($data);
        }
    }

    public function mapToModel(object $data)
    {
        return (object) [
            //
        ];
    }
}

class SettlementServiceTest extends MockeryTestCase
{
    public function test_ItWorks()
    {
        $mock_PDOStatement = \Mockery::spy(\PDOStatement::class);
        $mock_PDOStatement->shouldReceive('fetchAll')->once()->andReturn([(object) ['id' => '_id_']]);
        $mock_PDO = \Mockery::spy(\PDO::class);
        $mock_PDO->shouldReceive('prepare')->once()->andReturn($mock_PDOStatement);

        $settlementDB = new SettlementDB($mock_PDO);
        $settlementDB->getAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you only call the generator function or do you do as well something with the result of the call? Sharing the test-case method could help here with your question, maybe consider adding it (or a simplified example similar to the well done examples in your question). Also for completeness, it's also good to share the Phpunit version number on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @hakre - See update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANSWER FROM OP**

This is actually really simple I can't believe I missed it. The code inside `getValues()`, because it's a generator, is just simply not run until it's used inside an iterator like a foreach loop.

So if we add a foreach in the test, the code coverage will reach in to the `getValues()` function.

Eg:

```
$result = $settlementDB->getAll();

foreach ($result as $row) { 
}
```